# Get Shape from selected Edges

Tags: python, maya, pymel

Im using Maya to perform a certain task on selected edges.

Let's say I save these edges like this:

`edges = pm.filterExpand(sm=32)`

From here, I can just select the first edge, and get the object by splitting the unicode string:

`'pSphere1.e[274]'`

Here's how I split it, and it gave me pSphere1, however calling getShape() on that still doesn't work because it's a unicode object.

`object = edges[0].split('.')[0].getShape()`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can do `eval('pSphere1')` to get the object, but there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: Surely there's something that Pymel can do for this that the maya.core couldn't, I know of eval, I could also do `PyNode('pSphere1').getShape()`, but again, there should be another method @PauloAlmeida

Comment: @ShannonHochkins `PyNode()` is your best bet here because it assigns your string to the propper class which is what gives you all your methods and is the base function of PyMEL.. You can also run `pSphere1.e` to get all the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the shape from the edge, by simply listing it's immediate connection with the use of `node()`

**PYMEL:**

`pm.PyNode(selection[0].node().getParent())`

No need to split the string, or re map the array.

Answer (score 2):

EFilterExpand always returns strings (whether called from cmds or pm).  Use PyNode to convert:

```
mesh_edges = map(pm.PyNode, pm.filterExpand(sm=32))
for item in mesh_edges: 
        print item.node(), item.indices()[0]
```